# Watson Text-to-Speech via C++ Boost Websockets - "No such host is known"

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, ibm-watson, boost-beast

I've been unable to connect to Watson's Text-To-Speech service via websockets in C++ using the Boost Beast library

I've got code that successfully interfaces with echo.websocket.org on port 80, but it does not work with Watson's url. I've tried using variants of protocols (http(s), ws(s), and unspecified (which works for echo.websocket.com)) and I've tried both port 80 and 443, just to be sure.

I was able to get successful code running in Javascript, and using Firefox's inbuilt networking tool, I've verified it works over port 443. Using the exact same URL and port number gives me the following: "No such host is known."

Here is the relevant JS code that correctly establishes connection

```
var completeUrl = "wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?access_token=" + accessToken + "&voice=en-US_AllisonVoice";
socket = new WebSocket(completeUrl);
```

The following C++ code works fine in theory, and works with echo.websocket.org on port 80, but not Watson.

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;               // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
namespace websocket = boost::beast::websocket;  // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        std::string accessToken = "XXXXX";
        auto const text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

        std::string baseURL = "wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize";
        std::string voiceModel = "en-US_AllisonVoice";
        auto const port = "443";    // port 80 for echo.websocket.org
                                    // port 443 for watson

        std::string const host = baseURL + "?access_token=" + accessToken + "&voice=" + voiceModel;
        //std::string const host = "echo.websocket.org";

        boost::asio::io_context ioc;
        tcp::resolver resolver{ ioc };
        websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws{ ioc };

        auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);      // Problem line - "resolve: No such host is known"
        std::cout << "Host resolved" << std::endl;

        boost::asio::connect(ws.next_layer(), results.begin(), results.end());
        ws.handshake(host, "/");
        std::cout << "Connection established" << std::endl << "------------------------------" << std::endl;

        ws.write(boost::asio::buffer(std::string(text)));
        std::cout << "Client request: " << text << std::endl;
        boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer;
        ws.read(buffer);
        ws.close(websocket::close_code::normal);

        std::cout << "Server response: " << boost::beast::buffers(buffer.data()) << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If the Watson URL was wrong, it shouldn't work in Javascript. If the C++ code was wrong, it shouldn't work with echo.websocket.org. So I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: Did you solve this one?

Answer (score 1):

The `baseURL` in your code specifies "wss" which means Secure Websockets (SSL). But your `stream` is delcared as a plain stream. If you want to connect to secure websocket servers, you should base your code on the websocket-client-ssl example instead:
https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/d43d9421a40c0251614bc45ea6dcf921a3dbaf37/example/websocket/client/sync-ssl/websocket_client_sync_ssl.cpp#L64